# What equipment will allow 10m active USB cable to make self-powered USB peripherals work?

Tags: usb

I know, that this theme (about long USB cables) was discussed many times on different resources, but my question still keeps uncovered.

The task is typical: my PC is in one room, my TV is in another. I want to play on my TV (by using joystick) or control my PC by using TV as monitor.

The distance between PC and TV about 8 meters. As you probably knows, USB cables has a distance limitation of 5 meters. I seen (and already ordered a pair) adapter USB - RJ45 - USB. But, unfortunately, I couldn't find this kind of an adapter that will support USB 2.0, only USB 1.1. Well, I found a few, but they costs too much - from 50$.

Then I found long USB cables which are called active (with IC on one of the ends), it looks as following

[image: 1]

But there a lot of suggestions to not to use it with power consumable devices, only for something simple, like mouse. So, this doesn't fit my requirements.

**Is there an active cable and active USB hub that I can use to span the distance of 8m?**

Answer (score 2):

You're right: it'll work as long as the last hub will be a powered one. Remember that you have only 5 hops 5 meter cables which gives 20m tops (because last hop is from hub to USB keyboard/gamepad.

IMHO buying "active" cables is pointless, you'll be better of buying few regular, 4-port hubs and 5-meter cables.

But this all is unnecessary hassle: have you tried using wireless keyboard, mouse and joypad? They usually work very good over several meters and walls at home. If they don't, use **one** usb cable to position receiver better, this does the trick in most cases.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.